# Mongoose virtual array undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like:

```
const FeedSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  posts: {
    type: [{
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'post',
    }],
  },
}, {
  toObject: { getters: true, virtuals: true },
  toJSON: { getters: true, virtuals: true },  
});
```

When I run a query which tries to get the `postCount` virtual (below), it doesn't work as intended.

```
FeedSchema.virtual('postCount').get(function () {
  // console.log(this.title) <--- works fine
  // console.log(this.posts) <--- undefined
  return this.posts.length;
});
```

Why would `this.posts` be `undefined`? I suspect it's something to do with the fact that it's an Array of references.

As such, what's the correct way to do this?

Update:

This is the function which tries to get the details for one Feed:

```
async function getFeedShallow({ url }) {
  try {
    const shallowFeed = await this.findOne({ url }).select('-_id url title postCount');
    console.log(shallowFeed);
    return shallowFeed;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's happening when you log `console.log(this);`

Comment: Can't do that as it ends up recursively calling `toJSON()`.

Comment: Ouch... Just curious to know what's there in it.

Comment: Yep, I can't print it because I get a recursion error :(

Comment: It works for me. How do you call `postCount`?

Comment: @L.Meyer I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For visitors from the future, changing function to this solved the issue:

```
async function getFeedShallow({ url }) {
  try {
    const shallowFeed = await this.findOne({ url }).select('-_id');
    return shallowFeed;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: so the issue is related with that the field was excluded in select() method. thank you for the hint!!!